# Avoid extra spaces while pasting block with different line lengths

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have the text

```
var1=a
var2=aaa
var3=aaaaaa

some text... "" ...
some text... "" ...
some text... "" ...
```

I want to paste the `a`-part of the top 3 lines into the quotes in the last 3 line. The result should look like this

```
some text... "a" ...
some text... "aaa" ...
some text... "aaaaaa" ...
```

Now using Vim block selection <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, selecting block of `a` til the end of each line using <kbd>$</kbd> and then pasting it into the first `""` gives me the wrong result:

```
some text... "a     " ...
some text... "aaa   " ...
some text... "aaaaaa" ...
```

As you can see, vim aligns pasted text by adding extra spaces, that I don't need in my case.

Why Vim inserting those spaces and how can I paste my block without those extra spaces get added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's the standard behaviour, as far as I know. [As detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16943077/4113789), if you check the contents of your registers via `:reg`, you'll see the whitespaces between linebreaks and text.